# 3 boolean fiels or 1 field with 3 values - Relational Model DB

Tags: sql, database, database-design, mysqli, relational-database

This might be a very simple question but I wonder which would be the better way to do it under the relational model point of view.

I have 3 types of users:

- Customer
- Staff Member
- Super Customer

All of them **have the exact same fields**. I have all of them in the same `users` table, which also makes things easier to work with the framework I'm using.

My question is: is it better to use 3 different boolean fields to difference each type of user or just one field with 3 values?

Currently i have 3 boolean fiels: **admin**, **staff**, **superuser**.

Would that be more clear than creating just only 1 field with 3 values? (for example, 1 for admin, 2 for staff and 3 for superuser)

Thanks.

Comment: It depends: Can a user belong to multiple user types? If so, using one field will get tricky.

Comment: if u already know the number of type ENUM('one', 'two', 'three')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest one field perhaps a foreign key to a UserType table, something like this:

```
-- UserType table
-- UserTypeID INT -- PK
-- Type NVARCHAR(50)
```

and in you user table add one field `UserTypeID`.

Some users prefer readability so use a one character char field instead of an integer ID when they know the `types` list will be relatively short.

Comment: i agree with this, as long as users can be only of one of the types (1-n), you should just use 1 field.

Answer (score 1):

If a user can belong to only one user type: Use one field with three values.

If a user can belong to more than one user type: Use three boolean fields.

Comment: if user falls to multiple type will it be good to keep another table for type?

Comment: @ArunKillu: Yes. Even if it is just a mapping between the value (1, 2, 3) and the name (admin, staff, superuser). In that case it would act as a lookup table and define the meaning of each value.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Not really. Querying this will be real messy. And the data in the column is rather obscure.